# Has_and_belongs_to_many in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, relational-database, has-many

I've tried to look through stackoverflow to remedy my situation but unfortunately I've just made myself thoroughly confused.

I have two has_many to has_many relationships: Users has_and_belongs_to_many Roles, and Roles has_and_belongs_to_many Pods. I've already set up the correct tables and everything (i.e. the role_users and pod_roles tables): I know it's at least partially working because I'm able to do @user.roles and get all of that user's roles.

However, I want to take it one step further: I want to be able to do something akin to @user.roles.pods to get all of the pods pertaining to that user. After @user.roles.pods didn't work: here's what I tried to do:

```
@current_user_roles = current_user.roles
@pods = Array.new
@current_user_roles.each do |role|
  @pods.push(role.pods)
end
@pods.each do |pod|
  puts(pod.name+"-----------------")
end
```

Didn't work. This is just to try to get something super simple -- to try to get all of the pods' names to appear to I can tell if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could try:

```
@pods = current_user.roles.collect { |role| role.pods }.flatten
```